# Unable to move an image in HTML

Tags: html

I am having an issue were i can move an image, no matter what i type it stays in the top right half cut out with no scrolling

```css
.container_767 {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
}

.imagetext_767 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.image_767 {
  position: relative;
  width: 45%;
  height: 45%;
  left: 50%;
  bottom: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="container_767">
  <img class="image_767" src="../images/aircraft/CS767_TN.JPG">
  <div class="imagetext_767">Captain Sim 767</div>
</div>
```

Comment: That's because you are using `position: absolute`

Comment: @CharlieSchuyler What is the desired outcome? You wrote "i can move an image" I think you meant "I cannot ...". Please update the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the `position: absolute;` to `position: relative;` in the `.imagetext_767`

```
.imagetext_767 {
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use CSS properties like `left`, `right`, `top` and `bottom`, the element have to has property `position` set to value [`absolute`](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_position.asp). Then you will be able to position it to its first parent, which has property `position` set to value `relative`. If there is no parent element with this property value, position is set acording to left top conrner of window.

In addition, to use property `top` or `bottom` to be computed by percents, parent element must has it's own height.

Look at code snippet to see the example.

```css
.container_767 {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  background: aliceblue;
  height: 500px;
}

.imagetext_767 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.image_767 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 45%;
  height: 45%;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="container_767">
  <img class="image_767" src="../images/aircraft/CS767_TN.JPG">
  <div class="imagetext_767">Captain Sim 767</div>
</div>
```